# Xcode ignore storyboard warning

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, storyboard, ios9

How can I get Xcode to ignore this warning:

> Disabling segue animation is not available prior to iOS 9.0

I understand why the warning's there and am happy to ignore it because the app works just fine in 8.

I need to continue supporting iOS 8 and I don't want to suppress all storyboard warnings - just this one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the properties panel for your storyboard, set the 'builds for' drop down to a value of 9.0 or later

[image]

Comment: That didn't work - but it **did** work when I set it to 9.0. Seems to run OK on my v8.4 iPad too. Can you see any problems with that solution? Thanks!

Comment: No.. You're right.  You are telling your storyboard to present for 9.0 so that stops warning for lower versions.

Comment: Great, thanks. Can you edit your answer please then I'll give you the green tick :)

Comment: I want to try this too but I can't see the Interface Builder Document section. Is this gone in the latest XCode?

Comment: @Abizern  Will it be working for ios versions lower than 9.0? I need a minimum target of ios 8 and need to disable segue animation. Will this trick work? I dont have a device running ios 8.