# How to hide disabling segue animation is not available prior to iOS 9.0?

Tags: ios, xcode, segue

I am using Xcode 8.3.3 and need to use iOS 8.0 for some feature integration.
But I am getting a warning in Xcode 8.3.3 as Disabling segue animation is not available prior to iOS 9.0.
I want to remove this warning.

Comment: Duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/q/33147271/1986600. Please see the answers inside, any of first two will fit your needs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disabling segue animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33147271/disabling-segue-animation)

Comment: What's the development target of your project?

Answer (score 0):

UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("next", sender: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)

Comment: I want to remove this warning from Xcode . And in Xcode 8.3.3 , getting error as 'Property 'setAnimationsEnabled' not found of type UIView'. Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
 self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goToVC", sender: nil)
 UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
```

Comment: I want to remove this warning from Xcode .
And in Xcode 8.3.3 , getting error as 'Property 'setAnimationsEnabled' not found of type UIView'.
Kindly suggest.

Comment: Ok.Then try this `In the properties panel for your storyboard, set the 'builds for' drop down to a value of 9.0 or later`

Answer (score 0):

To disable that warning, Go to properties panel in your storyboard, and there you can see option **builds for** drop down.  Now change this value to 9.0 or later. Below is the picture that shows properties panel

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to suppress this warning. I tried this. Just modify the property in Attributes inspector of the segue which is causing the problem for you and then select the animates check mark. [image: select]